# Android How to only resize ScrollView on showing softkeyboard

Tags: android

So i have a layout that has a ToolBar above, a ScrollView with TextViews on it and 2 Buttons under the ScrollView. I need the Buttons to be under the SoftKeyboard when shown but making the ScrollView resize on the edge of the top of softkeyboard. I already added on the manifest
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
and on the ScrollView 
android:isScrollContainer="false"

The problem is i cant scroll on the edge of scrollview when keyboard is shown. So I need to resize it on showing the keyboard 
Heres the Layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/map_new_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:isScrollContainer="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llRegInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                        style="@style/EditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                        style="@style/EditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="" />

                    ....
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--MoreEditTexts Inside LinearLayout Like Above-->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegBack"
                style="@style/RedButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/return_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegNext"
                style="@style/RedButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/next_text"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: better post your layout xml to see the structure so that people can see it and give you answer

Comment: edited the question with the layout

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to tell Android what to do when the SoftKeyboard appears?

```
getWindow()
    .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

(Take a look at all the values, to see which one fits your bill).

Comment: I also added that but the buttons below the Scrollview shifts above the keyboard.